# How to reload module in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script which loads pre defined variables from `myModule`. I would like to call this this script many times in such a way that each time `from myModule import *` will be called. Here is my code:

```
# myModule.py
x = 12 # here I have one variable but I would like to make it works with maaany of them

# script
from myModule import *  # here I'm importing all variables (especially x)
another_variable = x * 2
```

at the runtime I will rewrite the variables in `myModule` and I will call this script again, but then the value of `x` will still be `12`. How can I somehow remove all variables which were imported from `myModule` so when I call `from myModule import *` the new values will be imported? I would like to remove all of them automatically

Comment: Python caches imports, so it doesn't matter if you re-import something - you'll get the same contents again.

Comment: So how can I remove it from cache?

Comment: I'm sure there are questions here that go into that, one has an answer I wrote suggesting `reload`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11618688/5987 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32234323/5987.